# how can i generate this series of sequence using recursion?

Tags: string, recursion, implementation

the question goes like this
We define sequences
Sn   ​as follows.

S1
​is a sequence of length 1 containing a single 1.
Sn(n is an integer greater than or equal to 2) is a sequence obtained by concatenating
Sn−1​ ,n,Sn−1
​in this order.

For example,
S
2
​
and
S
3
​
is defined as follows.

S
2
​
is a concatenation of
S1
​
,
2, and
S1
​
, in this order, so it is
1,2,1.
S3
​
is a concatenation of
S2
​
,
3, and
S2
​
, in this order, so it is
1,2,1,3,1,2,1.
Given
N, print the entire sequence
S
N
​
.

i want to create a string function and decrease it value using functions like **stoi** and genrate the sequence recursively and print the output

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem description you got already provided the recurrence relation and the base case:

- Base case: <sub>1</sub> = 1​
- Recurrence: ​ = <sub>−1</sub>​, , <sub>−1</sub>

And this is really it. You can formulate this in pseudo code like this, but it really is just a different syntax to express the same thing:

```vb
function S(n):
    if n == 1 then:  ' Base case
        output(1)
    else:            ' Recursion
        S(n-1)
        output(n)
        S(n-1)
    end if
```

I would actually shift the base case to <sub>0</sub> and define it as "nothing". Then the pseudo code becomes:

```vb
function S(n):
    if n > 0 then:
        S(n-1)
        output(n)
        S(n-1)
    end if
```

In an actual implementation in a programming language, you would replace `output` with whichever construct is appropriate. Like in Python you could go for a generator:

```py
def generate_S(n):
    if n > 0:
        yield from generate_S(n-1)
        yield n
        yield from generate_S(n-1)

print(*generate_S(3))
```

This outputs:

```
1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to a solution to the Hanoi towers puzzle.